# How to tell if there's an overflow page in SQLite?

Tags: database, sqlite

I'm traversing the SQLite database file as described in the file format specifications, but I'm not really understanding the part where we have to determine whether or not there's going to be a pointer to the overflow page in the cell header. As described here https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html
section 1.6, The entire payload will fit in the page if p < X, where X is U-35 (p is payload size and U is page size - reserved space).

I'm trying to read the sqlite_master table at the root page right now and the first cell starts at byte 3164. The first varint decodes to 929 which is the size of the payload. The cell header size is 3 bytes including the size of the payload so that adds up perfectly to 4096 bytes. But what if I had a p > 929?

From the description given, any payload that is less than (page size - reserved space - 35) should fit within the page. Say that I have a page that is 4KB with 0 reserved byte spaces, then X is 4096 - 35 = 4061. What happens if I have a payload size of 4000 bytes with the same offset of 3164 for where the cell is starting? Or is this scenario not possible with how SQLite sets up its pages? I'm just a little confused that the formula is ignoring how the actual cell can start at the end of the page so shouldn't we consider the offset in the formula as well?